# Birt report - function as marker

Tags: function, report, birt, marker

In Birt report, is it possible to use a function/expression as a marker, instead of being limited to use a static value?
Can't find that option.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You should explain what you mean.

Comment: For example, in this link http://jmini.developpez.com/eclipse_birt/charting_engine/gallery/marker_line_script/marker_line_script.png , there is a marker y=2. I want to use a marker that is not a value, but a function.

Answer (score 0):

No but you can make markers dynamic using chart scripting abilities in beforeDrawMarkerLine event. [For instance in this sample](http://www.visioneo.org/economic-country-detail), markers are bound to report parameters

```
function beforeDrawMarkerLine( axis, markerLine, icsc )
{
  importPackage( Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.data.impl );
  markerLine.setValue(NumberDataElementImpl.create(/*yourDecimalIndexValueOnAxis*/));
}
```